# The meaning of the sum of partial derivatives of a scalar function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, terminology, partial-derivative

I have a real valued function $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and it is important for me to add the coordinates of his gradient. In other words, if $u$ is the vector $(1, \dots, 1)$ I want to evaluate:
  $$\operatorname{div}(u \cdot f)$$
However strictly speaking this is not the divergence of $f$ since $f$ is not a vector field. Has anybody any idea if this corresponds to something specific in mathematics or physics? Can I, by abuse of language say that I have the "divergence" of a scalar function?

Comment: With your notation $\nabla(u \cdot f)=u \nabla(f) + f \nabla(u)= u \nabla(f)$. So you can consider it as the scalar product of the gradient of f and u.

Comment: Yes of course, but I need a physical meaning. For instance, I found that in some "normal" circumstances this is equal to zero. What does it mean geometrically ? Of course perpendicularity. But what can conclude for the scalar function f when it happens.

Comment: For instance can I say (i am not a mathematic but a theoretical computer scientist :-)) that f, which is always positive or zero, is minimal at the hyper plane depending from u ?

Answer (score 1):

The sum of first-order partial derivatives has the meaning of [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) along the vector $u=(1,1,\dots,1)$. In physical terms, this is the rate of change of $f$ observed by someone moving with velocity $u$.

In some texts, the notion of directional derivatives is restricted to unit vectors; if so, then we are looking at $\sqrt{n}$ times the directional derivative along the unit vector  $(1/\sqrt{n},\dots, 1/\sqrt{n})$.